# Can you make $\rm H_2O$ out of the air with tools anyone has?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, physical-chemistry, air

I was just wondering if you could make $\rm H_2O$ out of the air with tools that everyone has?

Comment: Water is in the air (see: humidity).

Comment: Yes but can you isolate it with common tools.

Comment: Yes. With a dehumidifier.

Comment: Or with a glass of ice water - if the humidity is high enough the glass 'sweats' - that is water condensing from the air on the cold surface.

Answer (score 3):

This is an active area of research to be able to do it efficiently. A lot of that research has to do with new materials or clever ways to increase the collection area.

However, you can get moisture from the air just by cooling something down below the dew point, and have the water condense on the cold surface. Dehumidifiers for example blow the rooms air past cool coils, and the result is water you need to drain or remove from a small bucket.